# Splitting a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

What would be a nice way to split the list

```
list = {1,2,3,{a,b,c},4}
```

into

> ```
> {{1,2,3,a,4},{1,2,3,b,4},{1,2,3,c,4}}
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Thread@list
```

gives

```
{{1, 2, 3, a, 4}, {1, 2, 3, b, 4}, {1, 2, 3, c, 4}}
```

Comment: arg! beat me to it! +1

Answer (score 3):

```
Distribute[list, List]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, a, 4}, {1, 2, 3, b, 4}, {1, 2, 3, c, 4}}

Answer (score 2):

```
With[{pos = Position[list, _List][[1, 1]]}, 
 ReplacePart[list, pos -> #] & /@ list[[pos]]]
(*{{1, 2, 3, a, 4}, {1, 2, 3, b, 4}, {1, 2, 3, c, 4}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I accepted a different answer because the way I phrased the question it was technically better, but this answer is closer to what I really needed in practice!

Answer (score 1):

```
ReplacePart[list, 4 -> #] & /@ list[[4]]
(*{{1, 2, 3, a, 4}, {1, 2, 3, b, 4}, {1, 2, 3, c, 4}}*)
```