# Splitting a list of lists (part2)

Tags: list-manipulation

This is a follow up from
[Splitting a list of lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66162/splitting-a-list-of-lists) .

What would be a nice way to split the list

```
l1 = {1,2,{a,b,c},3,{d,e}}
```

into

> ```
> {{1,2,a,3,d},{1,2,a,3,e},{1,2,b,3,d},{1,2,b,3,e},{1,2,c,3,d},{1,2,c,3,e}}
> ```

?

Comment: You'll probably be very interested in this docs : [Structural Operations on Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StructuralOperationsOnExpressions.html), and [Rearranging & Restructuring Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RearrangingAndRestructuringLists.html). In particular see the various Tutorials under "Learning Ressources".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
Distribute[l1, List]
```

Comment: ...thank you for introducing me to `Distribute`! :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach:

```
Tuples[Replace[l1, x_?AtomQ :> {x}, {1}]]
```

yields:

```
(*{{1, 2, a, 3, d}, {1, 2, a, 3, e}, {1, 2, b, 3, d}, {1, 2, b, 3, 
  e}, {1, 2, c, 3, d}, {1, 2, c, 3, e}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an other one which is not as "simple" as the other answers:

```
Evaluate@With[{pos = Flatten@Position[l1, _List]}, 
    ReplacePart[l1, Rule @@@ Thread[{pos, Slot /@ Range@Length@pos}]]] & @@@ 
    Tuples[Variables /@ l1 /. {} :> Sequence[]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, a, 3, d}, {1, 2, a, 3, e}, {1, 2, b, 3, d}, 
>  {1, 2, b, 3, e}, {1, 2, c, 3, d}, {1, 2, c, 3, e}}
> ```

Which is basically distributing

```
Tuples[Variables /@ l1 /. {} :> Sequence[]]
```

> ```
> {{a, d}, {a, e}, {b, d}, {b, e}, {c, d}, {c, e}}
> ```

over

```
Evaluate@With[{pos = Flatten@Position[l1, _List]}, 
  ReplacePart[l1, Rule @@@ Thread[{pos, Slot /@ Range@Length@pos}]]] &
```

> ```
> {1, 2, #1, 3, #2}
> ```